# Is there any way to get Command Line Arguments in the toolbar in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line-arguments

I know I can go through Project->Debugging->Command Arguments to set the command line arguments VS passes to my programs when I run them but is there anyway to move that field onto the toolbar so I can access it more quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's this extension here: [CLIArgsMadeEasy 2010/2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8159cd7d-2c81-47f3-9794-a347ec1fba09)

Comment: Isn't installable in VS2015 :(

Comment: Looking for something like this for VS2017

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way, but if you're just switching among a fixed set of command line arguments then you could create a separate build configuration for each.